# How do you structure your if statements, and what do you consider the easier-to-read of the two?

Tags: if-statement, structure

How do you structure your if statements, and what do you consider the easier-to-read of the two? As in:

```
if(condition){
    //... 
}
```

compared to

```
if(condition)
{
   //...
}
```

Comment: brace wars: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=758698

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the first method. It is easier to read, and in some cases, you may omit the {} (if one line is following the if statement).

Visual Studio can be set to do this automatically, and I'm sure other platforms can be set to format the code as well.